# iOs App unable to publish free app without accepting paid agreement can I resubmit my app without tier 1 pricing?

Tags: ios, publish

iOs App unable to publish free app without accepting paid agreement can I resubmit my app without tier 1 pricing?

Paid agreements states the following at the end.
You can still distribute your free apps without entering into the Paid Applications agreement.

Can I proceed without accepting this agreement my app is pending agreement but I want to start the process again as picked tier 1 pricing accidentally.